# Proving $|A_n|=n!/2$, where $A_n$ is the alternating group.

Tags: finite-groups, permutations

In the book: Theory and Problems Abstract Algebra Schaum's Outline Series by J. FANG:

He proved that $|A_n|=n!/2$, but in proof there is one thing that I did not understand, here is proof.(page: 83)

[image]

He first found $s\le r$ but how? He defined all odd permutations are $q_1,q_2,...,q_s$ and when you multiply even permutations, with a transposition you get odd permutations (we cannot say: all the odd permutations) , so I think it must $r\le s$ not $s\le r$. Moreover, the same logic follows in the last paragraph $r\le s$, again, it must $s\le r$.

What do you think whether FANG, or me is right?

Comment: By the way, except ordering $r\le s$ and $s\le r$, the proof is good with me.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The author accidentally _transposed_ his comparisons. But as you noted, once that's corrected, the proof is good.

Comment: And, what do you think, was he supposed to show that $S_n=A_n\cup t\circ A_n$ because may be $t$ multiply with $A_n$ cannot create all odd permutation in $S_n$

Comment: Once he gets the equality $r=s$, his maps are bijections (injective maps between two finite sets of the same cardinality must be surjective). And the two sets are of course distinct. Thus, any transposition $t$ applied to $A_n$ yields the entire complement of $A_n$. And conversely, any transposition $t$ applied to the complement of $A_n$ yields $A_n$ (all of it).